# Calling mapping (uint ==> bytes32)return 0x0000000

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design, mapping, bytes32

```
contract test{

  mapping(uint8 => bytes32) public check;
  uint8 [] public array;

  function Adddata(string document, uint8 number)  returns (bytes32) {
    check[number] = sha256(document);
    array.push(number);
    return check[number]; 

  }

  function Getdata(uint8 number) returns(bytes32){
    return check[number];
  }
}
```

so this is a simple test contract, I suppose to call Adddata to with a number a string, it maps an uint8 to bytes32(sha256 would convert string to bytes)

So if I call Adddata function, it will return me the sha256 of the stirng, but when I call Getdata afterwards, it returns me 0x000000000 whatever what input I gave...

Anyone know what happened?

Comment: module.exports = function(app, contract_address) {
  console.log('contract running at: ', contract_address);
  var MyContract = new web3.eth.Contract(abi, contract_address);
  var word = "abc";
  var num = 2;
  MyContract.methods.Adddata(word,num).call({from: '0x3423a830a195300863ffcb9dcadbae2834396c29'}, function(error, result){
      console.log(result);
  })

  MyContract.methods.Getdata(1).call({from: '0x3423a830a195300863ffcb9dcadbae2834396c29'}, function(error, result){
      console.log(result);
  }); // this is my JS code, what should I do to prevent that problem?

Comment: Please edit your post to include the JavaScript, as that is where the problem lies. I believe the issue is `MyContract.methods.Adddata(word,num).call`. `Adddata` mutates state, so it needs to be invoked via a transaction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works as expected. I think I would focus my bug hunt on the way you are interacting with the contract. A common error is to overlook the need to wait for the sent transactions to be mined. If you thunder ahead and `GetData()` before the transaction is mined, then you will find the contract state isn't updated as expected. This extra step is something Remix and Truffle tests fo "for free" so it is easy to overlook.

Here is the contract in Remix to show it working as expected. I might at that the `uin8` looks like an attempt to reduce cost but it won't have quite as impact as you might expect, other than limiting the range of possible keys, so I would consider going with a regular `uint` to maximimze capacity.

Hope it helps.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, right on remix it looks fine. and when I use node js and web3 it got problem.

Comment: In NodeJS, you'll typically get a transaction receipt in the callback. This indicates the transaction was successfully submitted. Here's a way to wait for that transaction to be mined and then carry on with `GetData()`. https://gist.github.com/xavierlepretre/88682e871f4ad07be4534ae560692ee6